# asp.net unpublishing

Tags: asp.net

I published my web application to a folder , after I hosted that folder on a server,but my project codes are broken.Now I will republish(unpublisch) my application from the publish folder. I will see my aspx page's .cs codes.how can I see

Comment: Can you make your question little more clear? You can see .cs code in Visual Studio.

Comment: when publishing a project the .cs codes are storing.So that we can't see the .cs files in publish fulder.But when I unpublish my project from publish folder I can see my .cs folder. is there any way to unpublis a published project

Comment: Are you saying that you are not seeing your `.aspx.cs` files and you want to "unpublish" those, if only you can see them?

Comment: Yes I'm not seeing .aspx.cs files in publish folder , bcause I published my project to a folder and that fils are stored

Comment: Its as expected. Publish wouldn't show .cs file.

Comment: can i unpublish from publish folder

Answer (score 0):

you have no choice to unpublish your code. While you work on the project before publish u have to take the copy of the project. while publishing ur codes are converted to dll. no way to recover ur codes from the dll.